# C++ Refactoring help

Tags: ros, c++

I am working with C++ for a Teensy (Arduino-like board). There is a pattern that I have a lot which annoys me because it is tedious and ugly. But I don't know how to refactor it to make it less repetitive and prettier. Here's the code (in simplified form)

```
void Arm::armCommand(String command, float arg)
{
    if (command == "wrist")
    {
        wrist((int)arg);
    }
    if (command == "elbow")
    {
        elbow((int)arg);
    }

    if (command == "shoulder")
    {
        shoulder((int)arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: if your code works without error, then it belongs at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: they may not know teensy c++ but sure ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that looks like it might be the direction you want to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473313/how-to-call-a-function-by-its-name-stdstring-in-c.

In summary, create a map between the string name and the function pointer, but here I'm assuming Teensy supports function pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt on this.

Here is how I solved this doubt: https://github.com/ConradLiuuu/strategy-sample-cpp/blob/master/include/cart.hpp

In master branch, I wrote the code like you.
In refactor branch, I wrote the code with `unordered_map` to save the functions, user passes the argument into interface function to call regarding sub-function.

Go back to your case, the concept may like this.  (I assume sub-function won't return a value)

I recommend you visit the link for more detail.
If you want to add new sub-functions in future, you only need to add static function and add it into unordered_map.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using MyFunctionType = function<void(int)>;

// public methods
unordered_map<string, MyFunctionType> commandFuncs()
{
  unordered_map<string, MyFunctionType> my_dict;

  my_dict["wrist"] = callWrist;
  my_dict["elbow"] = callElbow;
  my_dict["shoulder"] = callShouder;

  return my_dict;
}

void armCommand(const string& command, float arg)
{
  auto dict = this->commandFuncs();
  auto it = dict.find(command);

  if (it != dict.end())
  {
    return it->second((int)arg);
  }
  else
  {
    throw invalid_argument("command is not exist");
  }
}

// private methods
static void callWrist(int arg)
{
  wrist(arg);
}

static void callElbow(int arg)
{
  elbow(arg);
}

static void callShoulder(int arg)
{
  shoulder(arg);
}
```